# Dynamodb global index query all attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I query with local secondary index, I can retrieve both only projected or all attributes (with an additional latency). However, I can not get all attributes when I query with global secondary index, do we allowed to retrieve only projected attributes?

Answer (score 2):

When you create your table, you define the properties of your **Global secondary index**, choosing to project all attributes or only the minumum attributes (hash, range and global).

If you chose to create the global index with the minimum attributes and then you query for all attributes, those extra attributes will not be obtained (this is your case).

### The reason:

When you create the **global index selecting to project all attributes**, Amazon **duplicates** the extra attributes: attributes in the table and duplicated attributes associated to your global index.

Comment: Yes, this is same for local secondary index but we can retrieve attributes which are not in minimum attributes. If we won't retrieve some attributes very often then it does not need to be added to the minimum attributes. However, we are able to retrieve them with a cost. The problem is that this is not valid for global secondary index, that is, we can only retrieve minimum attributes and can not retrieve the others. For local indices, even if we define with minimum attributes, we can retrieve all attributes.

Comment: Thanks. So in the case we have a large table where we need all attributes regularly, and we create a GSI with unixtime as the hashkey, and query the GSI instead of the base table -- what we are essentially doing behind the scenes is creating two tables but using the second one which is the GSI table?

Answer (score 0):

I find answer, while creating table explanation is stated in tip.
"Projected attributes are attributes stored in the index and can be returned by index queries. Local Secondary Index queries can also return attributes that are not projected by fetching them from the table. **Global Secondary Index queries can only return projected attributes**. Note that projected attributes incur write and storage costs. For more information and performance tuning tip"